# Volver al estado inicial un componente de VUE (desde otro componente)

Tags: vue.js, vuex

> EDIT: Despues de pensar un rato se me ocurre que podria ser mas sencillo tener una propiedad computada en cada filtro (banos.vue, por ejemplo) que este observando el valor correspondiente de la tienda. Cuando este sea `{compare: '>', valor: ''}`, que vuelva el componente al estado inicial.
> No se como hacerlo aun, pero que dicen, es una mejor opcion?

En mi store de vuex tengo algo como:

```
 export default {
      namespaced: true,
      state: {
         toilet_amount: {
      //Cantidad de toilettes
      compare: '>',
      valor: ''
    },
    floors_amount: {
      //Cantidad de pisos
      compare: '>',
      valor: ''
    },
    room_amount: {
      // Cantidad de ambientes
      compare: '>',
      valor: ''
    },
    parking_lot_amount: {
      // Cantidad de cocheras
      compare: '>',
      valor: ''
    },

    bathroom_amount: {
      // Cantidad de baños
      compare: '>',
      valor: 0
    },
    age: [{
...
```

*(estos estados corresponden a filtros, que aplico para hacer una llamada a una API)*

Luego tengo un componente contenedor que tiene en su interior muchos componentes, cada cual corresponde a cada uno de los filtros de la tienda de vuex. Están correctamente realizadas las mutaciones y acciones, y se modifican correctamente.

Cada uno de los filtros se ve algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Importante (spoiler de mi pregunta): Cuando yo toco uno de estos 4 botones, este se pone verde, y se aplica ese filtro. Puedo tener múltiples botones seleccionados. En el ejemplo de la imágen sólo tengo el filtro `1` seleccionado.

Este es el ejemplo de uno de esos componentes que modifican la tienda de filtros

> Banos.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <SelectButton
      v-model="value"
      :options="paymentOptions"
      optionLabel="name"
      :multiple="true"
      class="selectButtonFiltros"
      @click="
        getEl(value),
          cargarFiltro({ label: 'Baños', value: 'bathroom_amount', action: 'bathroomAmountAction' })
      "
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SelectButton from "primevue/selectbutton";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
import { ref } from "vue";

export default {
  setup(props, context) {
    const store = useStore();
    const value = ref();
    const seleccion = ref([]);
    const paymentOptions = ref([
      { name: "1", value: 1 },
      { name: "2", value: 2 },
      { name: "3", value: 3 },
      { name: "4+", value: 4 },
    ]);

    const getEl = async (e) => {
      seleccion.value = [...e.map((el) => el.name)];
      const arrayBanos = Object.values(seleccion.value);

      if (seleccion.value.length > 0) {
        if (arrayBanos.find((e) => e == "4+")) {
          let data = {
            compare: ">",
            valor: 3,
          };
          await store.dispatch("filtros/bathroomAmountAction", data);
        } else {
          let data = {
            compare: "in",
            valor: arrayBanos,
          };
          await store.dispatch("filtros/bathroomAmountAction", data);
        }
      }
    };

    const cargarFiltro = async (data) => {
      await store.dispatch("filtrosSeleccionados/filtrosSeleccionadosAction", data);
    };

    return { paymentOptions, value, getEl, cargarFiltro };
  },
  components: {
    SelectButton,
  },
};
</script>
```

Y finalmente tengo un componente de filtros seleccionados que está relacionado con otro estado de vuex (que tengo en otro módulo, es un array con los filtros que voy seleccionando), y me sirve para mostrar los filtros aplicados, y eliminarlos.

(Para poder eliminarlos utilizo el componente `Chip`de `Primevue` : https://primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/chip )

Cuando yo elijo un filtro, el estado muta correctamente, y aparece el `Chip` para que pueda eliminarlo. Cuando lo elimino, efectivamente modifico el estado y vuelvo el filtro a su valor por defecto. Hasta aca todo ocurre bien.

Pero lo que me falta es poder volver mi componente (`banos.vue`, por ejemplo) a su estado original. Quiero que los botones que están en verde, seleccionados, vuelvan a ponerse en gris para que se pueda cargar el filtro correspondiente desde cero, ya que el estado SI volvió a su estado (valga la redundancia) original, pero el componente que lo modificaba NO.

Es decir, quiero volver a verlo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi componente de filtros seleccionados:

```
<template>
  <div class="p-d-flex p-ai-center p-flex-column p-flex-sm-row">
    <Chip
      v-for="(item, index) in array"
      :key="index"
      :label="item.label"
      :allowDuplicate="false"
      class="p-mb-2 p-mr-2"
      :removable="true"
      @remove="removeFiltro(item)"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Chip from "primevue/chip";
import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";
import { useStore } from "vuex";
export default {
  setup(props, context) {
    const store = useStore();
    const array = ref([]);

    array.value = store.state.filtrosSeleccionados.filtrosSeleccionados;

    const removeFiltro = (item) => {
      let pos = array.value.indexOf(item);
      array.value.splice(pos, 1);
      store.dispatch(
        "filtrosSeleccionados/filtrosSeleccionadosAction",
        array.value
      );
      let data = {compare: '>', valor: ''}
      let string = 'filtros/'+item.action
       store.dispatch(
        string,
        data
      );
    };

    return {
      removeFiltro,
      array,
    };
  },
  components: {
    Chip,
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Necesitaría que mi funcion

```
const removeFiltro = (item) => {
      let pos = array.value.indexOf(item);
      array.value.splice(pos, 1);
      store.dispatch(
        "filtrosSeleccionados/filtrosSeleccionadosAction",
        array.value
      );
      let data = {compare: '>', valor: ''}
      let string = 'filtros/'+item.action
       store.dispatch(
        string,
        data
      );
    };
```

Además de hacer todo eso, identifique el componente correspondiente y lo vuelva a su estado inicial.

Comment: tu estado inicial es el estado en el que se crea el componente, con los valores por defecto. entonces, tenes que tener un metodo que lo devuelva al valor original, volviendo los datos a sus valores por defecto...

Comment: @gbianchi en un componente como el mencionado, ``banos.vue``, no hay un estado seteado. Como podria volverlo al estado inicial? (quisiera poder hacer alguna especie de reset, pero no entiendo el tema del estado, no tiene ninguno configurado, esperaba tener alguna función como resetComponent() jaja)